# Installing Python 2.5 on Mac 10.6, for GAE/Django-nonrel (and i'm a new mac user)

Tags: python, macos, google-app-engine, django-nonrel

My big problem here is that I'm 1 day into learning MacOSX so the basics need to be explained to me like I'm a 4 yr old.

I'm running OS 10.6, Snow Leopard, which comes with Python 2.6.

The real problem is getting [Aptana 2.0](http://www.aptana.com/products/studio2) to debug [Google App Engine SDK](http://code.google.com/appengine/downloads.html), which I [require PIL for image transforming](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/), which requires python 2.5, with the app using the [Django-nonrel](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-nonrel) framework (I realize I didn't make this easy on myself).

I'm already familiar with Python, Google App Engine and Django-nonrel, but getting this setup on a Mac I'm lost.

```
1) How do I install a 2.5 and not screw up my already install 2.6?
2) How do I change the python path?
```

[Info on how to install PIL on a mac](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/installingPIL.html)

[Mac PIL installer for Python 2.5](http://pythonmac.org/packages/py25-fat/index.html)

(Btw, I totally feel like a 80 yr old trying to program on this mac)

Comment: Why do you think PIL needs 2.5? The link you posted even says that it supports 2.6...

Comment: My snow leopard install shows both 2.5 and 2.6.

Comment: @Daenyth App Engine requires Python 2.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is probably to install Mac Ports:
http://www.macports.org/

Then from a terminal window:
    $ sudo port install python25

Afterwards, you should have python_select available, which you can use to change your symlinks.

Answer (score 3):

10.6 has python2.5 installed, but python2.6 is the default.  Use python2.5 manage.py instead of python manage.py.

You can also change default python:
defaults write com.apple.versioner.python Version 2.5

Changing the system wide python default may have unintended side affects depending on your setup.

In either situation, you will still want to use easy_install-2.5

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12274473/4688650) stackoverflow answer

> Instead of using brew to install into the entire system a really old
>   version of Python; consider using pythonbrew instead. It will isolate
>   the python install - a bit like virtual environment, but for Python
>   itself.

**[How to install pythonbrew](https://github.com/utahta/pythonbrew#installation)**

**[How to use pythonbrew](https://github.com/utahta/pythonbrew#usage)**