# How to install Python25 on my mac with Homebrew

Tags: python, macos, homebrew

I'm new to Mac's and Python. I want to install an older version of Python (2.5) on to the Mac (OS X 10.8.1).
I'm using homebrew as it's newer than MacPorts and I don't know enough to choose between them.

Following instructions I have installed Rails, mySQL, budle, pow - all sorts of stuff, but when I use the same technique to install python 2.5 it doesn't work.

I tried:

```
Axolotl:.pow neil$ brew search python25
homebrew/versions/python25

Axolotl:.pow neil$ brew install python25
Error: No available formula for python25 
Axolotl:.pow neil$ brew install homebrew/versions/python25
Error: No available formula for python25
```

Where am I going wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need such an old version of Python?

Comment: My daughter is working through a book "Hello World" [Manning] and it's easier for her if the examples in the book match what she actually types - eg print as a statement, not a function and so on.

Comment: There will be no difference between the examples if you use the version of Python that comes with osx; as they are backward compatible. Also, consider using an updated book. 2.5 is very old.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Needing to install an older version - for various reasons such as testing - is often a valid use case.  There are still large production systems out there having only python2.4

Answer (score 15, accepted):

python25 is available in the Homebrew-versions tap:

```
$ brew tap homebrew/versions
$ brew install python25
```

Comment: It says no available fornmula for python25

Answer (score 10):

I think the `brew tap homebrew/versions` tip is no longer valid...

I have added that to my Homebrew, however it appears to point to this repo: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-versions

...and that does not contain any Python versions.

```
$ brew search python25
No formula found for "python25".
```

So if you want to install a specific version other than latest 2.7.x or 3.x.x you need a different method, what worked for me is:

```
brew install pyenv
(complete the install instructions)
pyenv install 2.5
```

You can then switch Python versions either globally (default) or just in current shell session, see: https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using brew to install into the entire system a really old version of Python; consider using [pythonbrew](https://github.com/utahta/pythonbrew) instead. It will isolate the python install - a bit like virtual environment, but for Python itself.

Answer (score 1):

You're not doing anything wrong, I'm afraid you're just out of luck. Have a look on the [list](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/tree/master/Library/Formula) of formulae available: no Python2.5.

There could be a workaround: copy the `python.rb` gem and edit the lines mentioning a version number, switching from 2.7 to 2.5. Careful with line 31 (the `sha1` signature), you'll want to edit that too.

Comment: The link is broken.