# Converting Blogger XML file into Wordpress WXR - Creating Python conversion script

Tags: python, xml, linux, wordpress, blogger

I'm currently trying to migrate my Blogger site over onto Wordpress; however, the XML file is too large to use as standard with the Blogger Importer Tool provided as a Wordpress Plugin.

Therefore I'm trying to use the WXRsplit program to split the file into more manageable chunks. However I can't seem to find anywhere that I'm able to convert from XML to WXR. The only site everyone is recommending, http://bloggerwordpress1.appspot.com/, is currently down with no notice as to when it might be next up, if at all.

If anyone knows how to make this conversion I would really appreciate the help.

---

Edit:

https://code.google.com/p/google-blog-converters-appengine/

So I have found this, which is apparently the codebase for the same site which I noted above that is currently down. However, I have no idea how Python works.

I do however have my own AWS server, running Linux Ubuntu 14.0 LTS, which I have full access to. I am currently trying to get my head around how to run these scripts but I'm having no luck as of yet; so, again, any help is apprectiated!

Thanks.

---

Edit 2:

So these are the two possibilities I've found so far that appear to produce any sort of result or error I can work from. I'm providing them here just to give more understanding to people looking at a glance who may not have used this particular program, but may gain some idea of what I'm doing wrong!

```
ubuntu@ip-:/var/www/html/pythonconversion/bin$ python blogger2wordpress.sh
  File "blogger2wordpress.sh", line 12
    PROJ_DIR=`dirname $0`/..
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax


ubuntu@ip-:/var/www/html/pythonconversion/src/blogger2wordpress$ python b2wp.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "b2wp.py", line 28, in <module>
    import wordpress
  File "/var/www/html/pythonconversion/src/blogger2wordpress/wordpress.py", line 55, in <module>
    element_tree_write = ElementTree.ElementTree._write
AttributeError: type object 'ElementTree' has no attribute '_write'
```

I'm not sure if I'm supposed to run the first or second command in order to try and get the script to execute. As I say, I'm 100% new to python and trying to piece together what little documentation I can find on this.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this blog](http://michael.f1337.com/2011/12/28/google-blog-converters-blogger2wordpress/), the problem was the script assumes python version 2.5.

> Blog Converters are built for Google’s App Engine, they require Python
>   2.5

If you are using mac and don't have python 2.5 installation by default (just like mine on El Captain), take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38521460/4688650).

On ubuntu, you may wanna use [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv).